# DrawableLeft programmatically on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-drawable

I'm working on a Xamarin Android app and I'm setting the following style to a button through my styles.xml

```
<style name="button_style_1" parent="@style/button_style_default">
  <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/my_icon</item>
  <item name="android:drawablePadding">28dp</item>
  <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Everything works fine but now I need to set the above properties to my button programmatically.
What's the best way to do it in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `drawableLeft`

```
 var draw = ContextCompat.Drawable(this, Resource.Drawable.your_drawable)
 button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
```

> Note : `this` is context of the Activity.

For `drawablePadding` use `CompoundDrawablePadding`.

For `padding` use `SetPadding`.

**Important Note :**

> `CompoundDrawablePadding` with a `negative padding` and `SetPadding`
>   with a `positive padding` to counter creates a `centered effect`.

just check it out and tell me.

Comment: Thanks. How to set drawablePadding and padding too?

Comment: I had some problems with the position of the elements but the way is the one you indicate. Thanks!